# Pytoapp only works from terminal, running from .app crashes

Tags: python, py2app

So I have a rather weird problem, I have a python application built using python3.7 and PyQT5.

I bundled it with py2app and when I double click it to start, it works ok but when I push a button that does a big series of commands, it crashes. The weird thing is if I do the same but open the application using the terminal (either using the open command or the ./ command), the application works with no problem.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to actually debug this since the osx crash report doesn't really give me any useful info and it never crashes when running through python.

My setup:

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['spotify.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'iconfile':'icon.icns',}

setup(
    app=APP,
    name='SpotifyBOTAI',
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you could try using [pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller)